# Are spaces allowed in CSS stylesheet for an element?

Tags: html, css

I am using drupal actually and I'm trying to position an element using "views slideshow". this isn't really a drupal question ,more of a css queston, however, one of my elements is called:

```
<div class="views-slideshow-controls-bottom clear-block">
```

Here's an image of the element to get an idea of what I'm doing.

[image: screenshot]

But anyway, I made that class above in my stylesheet, but the change isn't showing up on my page. I'm trying to "float" those slide previews that are highlighted in the image to the RIGHT side of the image instead of below the image how it is now. I thought a simple "float:left;" would do, but for some reason that clear:both is staying in there, plus the floatleft isn't even appearing.

The class there has a space in the middle of it, so I was wondering if on the stylesheet, this is allowed?

```
.views-slideshow-controls-bottom clear-block {
float:left;
 }
```

For example, will the spaces allow the element to show or not? Thanks,.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to chain the classes together in your css with a `.`.

```
.views-slideshow-controls-bottom.clear-block {
float:left;           /* notice ^ */
}
```

Comment: yes, this worked, awesome thanks! will accept when it lets me

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select based on two classes, chain them like this:

```
.class1.class2
```

This basically translates to `any element with class "class1" and with class "class2"`

It works just the same was as something like `a.btn[href]` meaning `any element with tag name "a" and class "btn" and an "href" attribute` - by chaining without spaces, you apply further restrictions to the current element.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have space in class name cause when you give class attribute it will be considered as two seperate class